# How can I get tornado to print out the datetime when logging INFO?

Tags: python, tornado

I'm using the enable_pretty_logging option. It seems like there should be a way to configure it to print out the datetime along with the log, but right now it looks something like this

```
INFO:tornado.access:200 GET /?asg_names=asg_name (10.10.163.112) 1475.84ms
```

Is there a way to get it to print out the datetime as well?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the format used by `enable_pretty_logging`; that's the default `logging.basicConfig` format used by the python logging module. Tornado only enables "pretty" logging by default if nothing else has touched the logging configuration beforehand. Try inserting a call to `tornado.log.enable_pretty_logging()` early in your startup process, before anything else has a chance to use the logs.